# symbol lookup error gdbus

Tags: debian, symlink

Keep getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/gdbus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_date_copy
```

looking at:

```
root@server-sl:~# ldd /usr/bin/gdbus

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefddfa000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77eaa5e000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77eaa0a000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77eaa04000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77ea6f5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f77ea538000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f77ea4c4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f77ea4a1000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f77ea298000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f77ea07a000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f77e9e52000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f77e9e39000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f77e9ddd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f77e9dd6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f77eac33000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f77e9d84000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f77e9d7a000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f77e9d71000)
```

and checking this:

```
root@server-sl:~# ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0

    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 set 22 05:53 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.5800.1
```

I cannot find what's wrong.
I'm on a DebianLinux server-sl 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-11-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: version mismach between `libglib2.0-0` and `libglib2.0-bin`.

Comment: tried  apt install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin --reinstall it return libglib2.0-0/testing,now 2.58.1-2 amd64 [installed, auto]
libglib2.0-bin/testing,now 2.58.1-2 amd64 [installed, auto]

Comment: how can I remove the wrong version? I've removed the file and reinstalling goes to same result as above.

Comment: dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0:dpkg-query: no path for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0:

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar issue after upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04

Also got issues like slow ssh logins, slow dpkg and apt works (process always stucked for a long time during "processing triggers")

Solution was too simple:

```
ls -il /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so*
ls -il /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so*
```

And I got a situation when

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4
```

Pointed to libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4 while

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4
```

Is pointing to a newer version.

So the solution is to remove files in /lib/ folder

```
rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4
```